# CsQuery Remove not working

Tags: csquery

Isn't this supposed to remove all Divs? It is not working for me.

```
 CQ cq = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.ebay.com");
 CQ newCq = cq["body"].Remove("div");
 string htmlCode = newCq.Render();  //The rendered code shows Divs present
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a parameter to `Remove` it's a filter, not a context-type selector, see http://api.jquery.com/remove/

So this code is only going to match `div` elements that are directly members of the selection, which only has one member, `body`.

To remove all divs that are within body:

```
CQ newCq = cq["body div"].Remove();
```